# Copying to byte array doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using System.Text;

var testString = "TestOneString";

var testStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testString);

var allBytes = new byte[testStringBytes.Length+2];

allBytes[0] = (byte) testStringBytes.Length;

Console.WriteLine("Length: " + allBytes[0]); // this is 13.

testStringBytes.CopyTo(allBytes,1); // It should be copied from 1 to 13. So the string is allBytes[1] to allBytes[13] or am I wrong?

var printTest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allBytes[1..(testStringBytes.Length)]); //allBytes[1..13]
Console.WriteLine(printTest); // this gives back: TestOneStrin

var printTest2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allBytes[1..(testStringBytes.Length+1)]); // why do I need to put the+1 there? this means this is allBytes[1..14]
Console.WriteLine(printTest2); // this gives back: TestOneString (the full thing).

/*However what I don't understand is, if (testStringBytes.Length+1) is 14
 * why can I change the 14th byte to anything and the string is still going to print normally? doesn't that mean that 14th byte has nothing to do with the string?
 */

allBytes[testStringBytes.Length + 1] = (byte) (new Random().Next());

var printTest3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allBytes[1..(testStringBytes.Length + 1)]);
Console.WriteLine(printTest3); // this gives back: TestOneString (the full thing).
                               // So why does it cut when I don't add +1 (which is 14, when the 14th byte has nothing to do with the string??)
```

The explanation of my problem is in the comments.

I'm copying string to byte array. The string has lenght of 13, and I'm starting at 1.
So it should copy to byteArray[1] .. byteArray[13] but, when I try to change the bytes 1 to 13 back to string, it cuts the last character out.
So I need to do byteArray[1] to 14, but, that doesn't make any sense as the 14th byte has nothing to do with the string. (The printTest3, shows that if I assign anything random to 14th byte the string is still full).

This is the console output of this program:

```
Length: 13
TestOneStrin
TestOneString
TestOneString
```

Can someone explain to me why do I need to do 1 to 14, if the 14th byte can be literally anything?

Comment: index starts at 0, so last entry is at byteArray[12] if length is 13

Comment: Im afraid I don't understand. testStringBytes.CopyTo(allBytes,1); means I start from 1 not from 0, which means that byteArray[12] would be only 12 characters? Which means it would cut one more character than it cuts now.

Comment: if the length is 13, you cannot copy the character at byteArray[13], because the last entry of the array is at byteArray[12]. Use a debugger and watch carefully the contents and indices

Comment: That makes no sense, did you see the code I posted? I'm starting at 1. not at 0. The string cannot end at 12, because when u print to 12 (i tried it), it cuts 2 characters from string.

Comment: So I took your advice, and viewed it using debugger. It is 1 to 13 as I expected, the problem is when I print 1 to 13 as string, it cuts last character nonetheless, when 1 to 14 (even when 14th is empty, or anything random) it prints the full string.

Comment: Because you string has 13 characters, and you start copying from index 1, which is the second character in your array, you should stop at index 14 which is the 13th position (counting from 0).  There is a difference between index (start at 0) and position (start at 1)

Comment: That makes much more sense now Luuk thank you!

Comment: To put it another way: the end point of a range is *exclusive*, not *inclusive*.

Answer (score 1):

In some environments like .NET or Java charaters may take more than one byte. Especially for UTF-8 encoding:

> This property returns a UTF8Encoding object that encodes Unicode
> (UTF-16-encoded) characters into a sequence of one to four bytes per
> character, and that decodes a UTF-8-encoded byte array to Unicode
> (UTF-16-encoded) characters. For information about the character
> encodings supported by .NET and a discussion of which Unicode encoding
> to use, see Character Encoding in .NET.

For [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-6.0).

For that reason you can't assume that your 13 characters string will take 13 bytes.

Comment: Hi, you might be right but in this case it is indeed 13 (viewed with debugger)

Comment: And the 13 is not the number of characters, it is the number which I got after encoding it (of the bytearray that came out of the string), so actually this is not the case.